# Unable to load images asynchronous with FSPagerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have problem displaying the images in the slider because I have to wait for them to download and then load them inside the FSPagerViewCell ImageView.

Inside the delegate function

```
- (FSPagerViewCell *)pagerView:(FSPagerView *)pagerView cellForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
```

I am using an async function which when the image is ready, returns the downloaded image.
I use

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
```

to load the image inside the FSPagerViewCell.imageView

but it doesn't show anything, just white space.

Here is the complete code:

```
- (FSPagerViewCell *)pagerView:(FSPagerView *)pagerView cellForItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    FSPagerViewCell *cell = [pagerView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"pagerCell" atIndex:index];

    if (index < [arrMediaGallery count])
    {
    pageControl.currentPage=index;

    MediaGallery *firstImage = arrMediaGallery[index];
    NSString *imageName = firstImage.Source;
    NSString *imageURL;

    if (imageName != nil && [imageName isEqualToString:@"NULL"] == NO && [imageName isEqualToString:@""] == NO) {

        imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"thumblarge_%@", imageName];
        imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/cache/photos/%@", [MyApp sharedInstance].settings.StaticURL, imageName];
    }

    UIImage *image = [NetworkUtilities resolveImageWithName:imageName];

    if (image == nil) {


        ProcessServerData *processData = [ProcessServerData new];
        [processData downloadImageForURL:imageURL verifyDownload:NO
                              verifyHash:nil
                            oldImageName:nil
                              parentView:[cell contentView]
                              completion:^(NSError *error) {

                                  UIImage* image = [NetworkUtilities resolveImageWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", imageName]];

                                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                                  [UIView transitionWithView:cell.imageView
                                                    duration:2.0f
                                                     options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                                                  animations:^{
                                                      [cell.imageView setImage:image];
                                                  } completion:nil];
                                  });


                              }];

    }
    else {
        [cell.imageView setImage:image];
    }

    }
    return cell;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Step:1 -**  install From "https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSPagerView"

**Step:2 -**  import "FSPagerViewDataSource,FSPagerViewDelegate" in VC

**Step:3 -**  implement methods

```
 //MARK: - FSPagerview Delegate and Datasource -
func numberOfItems(in pagerView: FSPagerView) -> Int
{
    if pagerView == self.News_images_View
    {
        return 3
    }
    else
    {
        return 3
    }
}

func pagerView(_ pagerView: FSPagerView, cellForItemAt index: Int) -> FSPagerViewCell
{
    let cell = pagerView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", at: index)
    cell.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true


    if pagerView == self.News_images_View
    {
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "noticia.jpg")
    }
    return cell
}

func pagerView(_ pagerView: FSPagerView, didSelectItemAt index: Int)
{
    if pagerView == self.News_images_View
    {

    }
}
```

> @IBOutlet var viewFirstAdvView: FSPagerView!

- Inside ViewDidLoad

> > self.viewFirstAdvView.register(FSPagerViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell") self.viewFirstAdvView.itemSize =
> >     CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height:
> >                 UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width / 2)
> >             self.viewFirstAdvView.isInfinite = true
> >             self.viewFirstAdvView.automaticSlidingInterval = 3.0
>
> self.lastAdvertiseView.transformer =
>   FSPagerViewTransformer(type:.crossFading)